# Apache camel : poll from more than one channels (say 2 pubsub topic ) , and then summarize the messages into one message

Tags: apache-camel

Hi I am struggling to find a documentation where I can poll more than one channel (say 2 pubsub topic or 2 files or 2 jms topic etc.) and then combine the messages into one .The intention is to summarize the multiple messages from the different channels into one message.

I know aggregation in camel will allow me to combine more than one messages into one.But how to aggregate when the two(or more) messages are from different channel.

Please point me to a link/documentation and I will figure out the rest.

thanks 
manjith

Comment: You can have a look at content enrichment using camel. https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/eips/enrich-eip.html

Comment: Thank you Sneharghya for your response.Will look into it.

Thanks
Manjit

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve it using Segmented routes approach. Here I am using direct channel, but you can use seda or vm as well. Please note

```
from("input-source-1").to("direct:composite-source"); 
from("input-source-2").to("direct:composite-source"); 

from("direct:composite-source")
    ....;
```

See https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_fuse/6.3/html/apache_camel_development_guide/basicprinciples-multipleinputs

Please note the following approach is deprecated in camel 3. (https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/camel-3-migration-guide.html)

```
from("URI1", "URI2", "URI3").to("DestinationUri");
```

Comment: Hi Kavithakaran this is fantastic idea.I didnt know we could do this.I am going with this approach....Thank you !!

Answer (score 0):

Camel does not have a composite message source like mule where you can put sources. So you will have to start two routes and then merge them.

Comment: Thank you Uma.Yes you are right.I have to go towards that strategy of starting two routes and then merge them